# Whatever test I created in my Angular project is failing due Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive NotFoundComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have an Angular project that whatever spec file I created to test any component is failing due Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive ...

For example, I created a component that contains some Material design tags, and belongs to a module called PagesModule, the component does not do anything:

pages.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from '../_shared/shared.module';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './error/not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [NotFoundComponent],
    imports: [SharedModule, RouterModule],
    exports: [],
    providers: []
})
export class PagesModule {}
```

not-found.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';

describe('NotFoundComponent', () => {
    let component: NotFoundComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotFoundComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [SharedModule],
            declarations: [NotFoundComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotFoundComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Additional information:
My SharedModule is already exporting all necessary material modules.

Comment: Use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in the module of your spec file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NotFoundComponent` may contain nested components or directives, whose templates may contain more components. There are basically two techniques to deal with this in your tests (see. [Nested component tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests)).

1. create and declare stub versions of the components and directives
2. add `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to the `TestBed.schemas` metadata.

When opting for the first solutions, your test could look something like this.

```
@Component({selector: 'app-nested', template: ''})
class NestedStubComponent {}

describe('NotFoundComponent', () => {
    ...

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [SharedModule],
            declarations: [NotFoundComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
```

When opting for the second solution, `TestBed.configureTestingModule` would have to be changed as follows.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [SharedModule],
    declarations: [NotFoundComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
}).compileComponents();
```